# Parallel processing or threading in Shell script

Tags: multithreading, shell

I am new in Parallel processing. I have some python scripts which I should not change them for some reasons. Each of these python scripts only use one cpu core and does some processing on an input image. I run these python scripts with a shell script one after another. Can I do paralel threading in shell script without thouching python scripts so that each python script uses multiple cpu cores and the processing speed on each image gets increasd?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, start them with **GNU Parallel**.

So, if you want to run your script 10 times, with parameters 0..9:

```
parallel python yourScript.py {} ::: {0..9}
```

If you want to see what would run without actually running anything:

```
parallel --dry-run ...
```

If you want a progress meter:

```
parallel --progress ...
```

Comment: Let us suppose that I want to run python script on only one image. So far, this python script uses only one cpu core to perform processing on this image. Can I call this python script in shell script in a specific way so that it uses more than one cpu core and perform processing on this image faster? Does your approach work for my problem?

Comment: It will not split an image up for you, spread the parts across CPUs, process in parallel and recombine the parts. If you have 8 images to process though, and 8 CPU cores, it will get close to getting all 8 images done in the time one normally takes - so your throughput will be 8 times greater but your latency to the first result unchanged.

Comment: If your image is enormous and your processing extremely complex and the processing of one area of an image independent of the others, it may be worthwhile to split the image yourself, and run each part through GNU Parallel as above, then recombine. You'd need to expand the detail in your question a lot.